# create mysql database with one line in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, mysql, database

Is it possible to create an empty database with one line of command in bash?

My newbie attempts have failed:

`mysql -uroot $(create database mydatabase;)`

I end up having to

- `mysql -uroot`
- `create database mydatabase;`
- `exit;`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

@Nitrodist's answer will work, but it's over-engineering the problem. MySQL's command-line client supports the very handy `-e` switch, like so:

```
mysql -uroot -e "create database 'foo'"
```

You can of course substitute any valid SQL into there.

Comment: The quotes are not required `mysql -uroot -e "create database foo"`

Comment: Yep, using additional single quotes gave me an `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''foo'' at line 1`. Without them it works fine. Thanks @IanVaughan

Answer (score 16):

According to MySQL's documentation, the `mysql` can take commands from `stdin`

```
shell> mysql -uroot < script.sql > output.tab
```

You can use [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to accomplish this:

```
shell> mysql -uroot <(echo "create database mydatabase;")
```

or you can just pipe it to the `stdin` of `mysql` normally:

```
shell> echo "create database mydatabase;" | mysql -uroot
```

Can't test this personally, but I think this should work.

**Edit:** Another option is to use the `-e` option, specified [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute), like so:

```
shell> mysql -uroot -e "create database mydatabase;"
```